# widget for implementing auto complete for search engine

Tags: javascript, search, autocomplete

I'm putting together a search engine.  I need a text field (with autocomplete) and a Search button.  (Clicking the Search button submits the form.)

There are many javascript autocomplete solutions out there (some are listed at http://webtecker.com/2008/03/10/10-auto-complete-ajax-scripts), but I need one that works in tandem with the Search button.

Specifically, I'm looking for a javascript widget that mimics the functionality provided by Firefox's search bar...  When the user types in the text field, the autocomplete presents suggestions in a drop-down.  If the user presses Enter (e.g. without touching the drop-down), then the form is submitted (as if the Search button was clicked), and what the user typed into the text field is the value that is submitted to the form.  Alternatively, if the user selects a value from the autocomplete drop-down (either via keyboard or mouse), then the text field's value is set to the autocomplete selection, and the form is submitted (as if the Search button was clicked).

I already have the server-side back-end code that generates the autocomplete suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery or don't mind using it, this [autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) works like that and is pretty customizable.

EDIT

You'll need a source of data for autocomplete hints - how you develop this is up to you.  Let's for the moment pretend that your entire universe of search suggestions is a list of months.  And your form will search Google with those suggestions.

Here's what a hint page might look like (in PHP)

**hint.php**

```
<?php

$query = $_GET['q'];

$monthList = array(
    'January'
  , 'February'
  , 'March'
  , 'April'
  , 'May'
  , 'June'
  , 'July'
  , 'August'
  , 'September'
  , 'October'
  , 'November'
  , 'December'
);

if ( preg_match_all( "/^" . preg_quote( $query ) . ".*$/im", implode( "\n", $monthList ), $matches ) )
{
  echo implode( "\n", $matches[0] );
}
```

So now we just need to hook up an autocomplete field to this page as its source of suggestions.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
    {
      $('#search').autocomplete( 'test.php', {} ).result( function( data, value )
      {
        $(this)[0].form.submit();
      } );            
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="http://www.google.com/search">

<input type="text" id="search" name="q"/><input type="submit" value="Search">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And of course, your search endpoint doesn't have to be Google - could be any other search including one of your own.

Comment: Really?  I didn't see any way to make the JQuery autocomplete plugin work in tandem with a Search button.  Can you point me to an example?

Comment: That's up to you to implement.  I'll modify my answer w/an example.

Comment: Still, my question was how to get the autocomplete to interact with both the text field AND the search button.  Your example doesn't address the Search button, so it's not very useful.

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean by "interact with"?  Because right now I'm not sure I understand the behavior you're after.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the "auto-submit-on-select" functionality? Of course you can do that.  It makes me wonder if you even bothered to read the documentation for the autocomplete plugin at all.  Answer modified to include this.